# In SSRS Reports, how can I set visibility to hide subtotal info in a row that is linked to other columns because of grouping?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reporting

I created a report to show purchase order (PO) info; some POs have multiple line items and some do not. I would like to show subtotals only when a PO has multiple line items. I am new to SSRS Reports and am still learning.[Screenshot of report fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBteR.jpg)

The only way I could figure out to compute the subtotals of each PO correctly was to use parent groups because my "Line Item Remaining" total is based on an expression (Line Item Amount less Line Item Liquidated). I tried setting the visibility of the subtotal row based on a condition, but my report comes back blank because the first 5 columns of the report are part of that row.

I was able to set the visibility to hide the subtotal info in the middle 4 columns when there is only one line item; however, the blank row still shows because it is linked to the first five columns because of grouping.

[Output of report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oZL1.jpg)Right now my workaround is to export to Excel and then filter out the rows that show “HIDE” in the last column, but I wanted to know if there was a cleaner way to do this all in SSRS.

This is the query I'm using:

```
`SELECT DISTINCT
  ap_purch_orders.a_purch_order_no
  ,ap_purch_orders.a_vendor_number
  ,ap_vendor.a_vendor_name
  ,ap_purch_orders.po_prep_date
  ,ap_purch_orders.po_gen_comments
  ,ap_purch_orders.po_request_dept_cd
  ,ap_purch_orders.pg_dollar_amount
  ,ap_purch_orders.pg_liquidated_amt
  ,ap_purch_orders.pd_line_item_desc
  ,ap_purch_orders.a_org
  ,ap_purch_orders.a_object
FROM
  ap_purch_orders
  INNER JOIN ap_vendor
    ON ap_purch_orders.a_vendor_number = ap_vendor.a_vendor_number
WHERE
  ap_purch_orders.po_request_dept_cd = N'RP'
  AND ap_purch_orders.po_status_code NOT IN (N'0', N'1', N'2', N'4', N'5')
GROUP BY 
   ap_purch_orders.a_purch_order_no
  ,ap_purch_orders.a_vendor_number
  ,ap_vendor.a_vendor_name
  ,ap_purch_orders.po_prep_date
  ,ap_purch_orders.po_gen_comments
  ,ap_purch_orders.po_request_dept_cd
  ,ap_purch_orders.pg_dollar_amount
  ,ap_purch_orders.pg_liquidated_amt
  ,ap_purch_orders.pd_line_item_desc
  ,ap_purch_orders.a_org
  ,ap_purch_orders.a_object``
```

[Subtotal Grouping Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYmnc.jpg)

This has been resolved. See screenshots below:
[Solution Part1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tqhhq.jpg)

[Solution Part2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4hmL.jpg)

Comment: A few questions. `1.` What row group does the subtotal row belong to? (click a cell on that group and see which row group is highlighted un the row group panel) . `2.` I assume the same expression you used to generate `"Hide"` is not working. `3.` What expression have you used to generate the `Hide` text?

Comment: Hi Alan, 1. The subtotal row belongs to the group for columns 1-7 (PO# through Line item amount). I added a new screenshot at the bottom of my post. 2. Correct, "hide" is not working because when I apply it to that row, it hides columns 1-7 as well since they are parent groups. 3. I used this expression on the four middle subtotal cells, under textbox properties>visibility>show or hide based on an expression: =IIF(COUNT(Fields!pg_dollar_amount.Value)<2,TRUE,FALSE)   Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, you've misunderstood. If you click on a cell from your subtotal row (e.g. the `[SUM(pg_dollar_amount)]`, then one of the rowgroups below should be highlighted. This will tell you which group it belongs to, I suspect it's the row group called `po_request_dept_cd`.

Comment: It is po_gen_comments I'll add that screenshot.

Comment: It probably needs to go into the request_dept, which incidentally is not in your dataset query? If you can script out some sample data I can reproduce this but I think all you need to do is ad a footer to the last group and put your subtotal there, you should be able to hide it without affecting any other rows.

Comment: Thank you Alan! You've been an immense help; I was able to fix my report. I think my issue was that I manually added a subtotal row instead of inserting it from the Row groups. The missing field from the dataset query was a typo (I updated it), and I changed the footer to the last group. I will add screenshots of how I corrected the report. Thanks again!!

Comment: No problem. You can add it manually too, it's just easier from the row group. You can do "Insert Row ==> Inside Group ==> Below" to do the same thing.